# Regex for numbers and specific special characters

Tags: regex

I am using this regex for validating numbers and specific set of special character.

```
([0-9]+[ \(\)-/#]*)$
```

This does not restrict special characters as specified. What is the problem with my regex.

thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to use start anchor `^` and avoid unnecessary escaping inside character class:

```
^([0-9]+[ ()/#-]*)$
```

- Start/end anchors will avoid the problem of matching unwanted input.
- Also note that hyphen avoids escaping if it is placed at first or last position inside character class

Comment: You should add a sentence about `-` not being at the start/end of a character group and thus (probably) being interpreted as a range.

Comment: that worked. i thought ^ indicates starting letter of the string, so by specifying it i assumed that the string should definitely start with numbers.

Comment: Thanks @BastiM: I added a note about it.